# Ускорение работы парсеров

Tags: php

Есть два парсера:

1.Парсит картинки

2.Парсит текст.

Вызываются эти два парсера по очереди.Максимальное время обработки всех темных дел составляет 2 cекунды.Вопрос,как можно сделать их работу паралельной без ожидания отрабоки одного из парсеров?

Comment: А Вы вызываете парсеры из консоли или как? Если мне нужно два скрипта параллельных запустить то я использую screen или два окошка терминала. Но это прокатывает в случае одинарных или очень редких задач

Comment: @S. Pronin В том то и дело что без консоли и через браузер.

Comment: Тогда можно вызвать оба парсера через AJAX, ну или один из них.

Answer (score 1):

Запускайте сразу два [асинхронных AJAX запроса](http://jquery-docs.ru/Ajax/jQuery.get/).

```
jQuery.get("job1.php");
jQuery.get("job2.php");
```